# CSV to Neptune bulk format

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Is there any API (offered by Neptune or otherwise) that converts tabular CSV files (the ones that Neo4j imports support) into Neptune Bulk CSV format (gremlin or openCypher), other than writing python lines for each use-case?

I have tried to write python code lines to do so but I expect a regularly used conversion tool because the Neptune supported format is very specific.

Thanks in advance.

Anita

Answer (score 1):

If you already have de-normalized data in a CSV format, then you could use the following utility: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/csv-to-neptune-bulk-format  This tool allows you to map an existing CSV file/schema to a Neptune Gremlin Bulk Load CSV format/schema.

If the data is normalized, or sourced from multiple files, then you may want to take an approach similar to:  https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-neptune-samples/tree/master/gremlin/etl-from-relational-model  In this approach, we're using TSV files and leveraging AWS Glue and Athena to detect and expose the schema in each file.  We can then write SQL queries to build the target CSV files for bulk loading.

If what you're doing is at small scale, then you may just want to load the data into something like SQLite and following a similar process to the above.

The data does not necessarily have to be de-normalized, but do realize that Neptune's bulk loader is limited when it comes up "upserting" data. It is mostly used as a means to initially load data or append new data into the graph.

You can certainly have multiple files where you can add/append properties to existing vertices/edges.  For example, if we have the following two CSV files:

```
~id, ~label, name:String(single)
nm0000102, Artist, Kevin Bacon
```

and

```
~id, ~label, birthYear:Int(single)
nm0000102, Artist, 1958
```

Loading those two files would result in a single vertex of label `Artist` and two properties: `name` and `birthYear`.

Comment: Thanks Taylor. I saw this repo but I'm not sure how this will work with multiple source CSV files with common columns to join on. Taking the spotify dataset as an e.g., suppose you have 'source_track.csv' that contains [track_ID, track_name, track_artist, album_ID] AND another CSV file 'source_album.csv' that contains [album_ID, album_name, album_release_date]. Now you want to create track node, album node and track->album edge, without duplicating album_ID.

Comment: Another questions is, if we later want to add more attributes to an already created node CSV file, is it possible to modify the existing CSV file to include more columns? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good point. That really only works with denormalized data.  I added a couple of additional approaches to my response.

Comment: Thanks Taylor. So for clarity, does that mean apart from https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-neptune-samples/tree/master/gremlin/etl-from-relational-model which involves AWS Glue, Athena and some SQL queries , there is no way one can do bulk load into Neptune database of data in multiple CSV files (normalized)?

Comment: It really depends.  I updated the answer above.  You can load multiple files with data related to the same vertices/edges, so the data does not need to be fully de-normalized.  But the data being loaded will need to be in a format (with headers) supported by Neptune's bulk loader.

Comment: If I use (https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/csv-to-neptune-bulk-format) to convert both the "raw" CSV files into neptune bulk format (the ones that you mention), won't it assign 2 different IDs (say, nm0000102 and nm0000103) to this node in the 2 neptune-bulk-format files? Is there a way in which, while specifying 2 "raw" input CSV files (f1 and f2) in the configuration (json) file, I can merge columns (col_f1 and col_f2) present in f1 and f2 by assigning same label to col_f1 and col_f2, so that common IDs are assigned which can then be used in edge file creation?

Comment: I understand that Neptune will create merged nodes as long as the ID is same, but the problem really is to get to the neptune-bulk-format using [this tool](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/tree/master/csv-to-neptune-bulk-format) in a way that it takes multiple "raw" CSV files with common columns to relate on (normalized), and produces single ID for the values in that common column.